# Strange calculation error

Tags: php

```
<?php
function neglogic($x,$y)
{
    if ($x<0.0 &&  $y>=0.0 )
    {
        $p1=("1");
    }
    elseif ($x<<0.0 &&  $y<<0.0 )
    {
        $p1=($x/$y);
    }
    if ($x==0.0 &&  $y>=0.0 )
    {
        $p1=("1");
    }
    elseif ($x==0.0 &&  $y<0.0 )
    {
        $p1=("0.05");
    }
    if ($x>0.0 && $y <=0.0)    
    { 
        $p1=("0.20");
    }
    elseif($x>0.0 && $y >0.0)
    {
        $q1=($x-$y);

        if ($q1>=0)
        {
            $p1=("0.20");
        }
        if ($q1<0)
        {
            $p1=("1.0");
        }
    }
    return $p1;
}
?>
```

This is the script it workd fine but I noticed it fails for values between (-1 to -0.001).

Please try the below It fails for the second (-.8,-2) saying $pq is undefined.

I know I can define $p1 at the beginning ,but I want to know why it fails for the second numbers.

```
<?php
echo neglogic(-8,-2);
?>
<?php
echo neglogic(-0.8,-2);
?>
```

Comment: Use proper indentation first. Then stop enclosing float values in double quotes. And note that `<<` is not a comparison operator.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I suppose elseif ($x<<0.0 &&  $y<<0.0 ) is incorrect

Comment: But is the "<<" typo only here, or also in the non-working code?

Answer (score 2):

In `elseif ($x<<0.0 &&  $y<<0.0 )`

"<<" does not mean less than in PHP.  It means shift left.

Did you mean shift left 0 places? or did you mean test less than `<`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

If the `"<<"` is in the code, it is valid code that will cause unintended behavior. i.e. a bug. Since shift left 0 bits does nothing, the if becomes if ($x && $y) which is true if both x and y are true when converted to boolean.  According to the PHP docs, 0 and various similar values are false, and everything else is true.  So the clause following the bug executes as long as x and y exist and are nonzero or otherwise both "true".  In particular the if clause can execute when x or y is positive, because a positive value is true, and that is unintended behavior if you thought you were testing less than 0.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: @user2300435 I added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous very strange styles in this code, but the one that jumps out the most is:

```
 elseif ($x<<0.0 &&  $y<<0.0 )
```

Do you really mean `<<` - this is bitwise left-shift operator, and since it's been passed 0 as the shift then it will nothing.

Do you mean `<`, for less-than comparison?